# Woocommerce - Shop page repeat the products with filters

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a website with shop page https://smitafashions.com/shop
and tried to recreate the shop page using the shortcode but failed

You can see after 3 products it shows a filter bar and then repeat the products so how to remove that filter bar and repeated products

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/shop` is a default woocommerce shop page.

Adding shortcode to the content of that page simply prepends it before the actual shop page.

Read more about it here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pages

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem